# @Transaction annotation with different data sources

Tags: java, spring, transactions, annotations

We have a use-case where we want to talk to different databases which support transactions and want to do it via the annotation that spring provides.

The way I see this annotation works is that it picks the default implementation of `PlatformTransactionManager` with the DataSource bean defined by the client and talks to that persistence layer.

So, to talk to another data source, I will have to provide a `TransactionManager` which overrides its `doBegin` method with the help of new data source.

But the problem here is that if I do that, there is no way for the `@Transaction` annotation to know about which data source to pick (I am not able to see how bootstrap works in these cases because I don't see a way bean conflict could arise - maybe I am missing something here).

One alternative I can think of is to create a new annotation @DataSourceAwareTransaction which accepts a parameter for the default data source and logic gets written in the new annotation.

The issue with this approach is that I will have to change all the existing code to move from @Transaction to @DataSourceAwareTransaction.

The approach I am describing looks reasonable enough? Does anyone have any better ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But the problem here is that if I do that, there is no way for the `@Transaction` annotation to know about which data source to pick....

Sure there is. Have a look at [@Transactional#transactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#transactionManager--). The relevant section states:

> *transactionManager* (*value* is an alias) 
> May be used to determine the target transaction manager, matching the qualifier value (or the bean name) of a specific [PlatformTransactionManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html) bean definition.

You can specify the transaction manager that you want `@Transactional` to use, and the transaction manager in turn is configured for a specific data source.

Example:

```
@Transactional("yourTransactionManager")
```

or

```
@Transactional(value = "yourTxManager", isolation = ..., propagation = ...)
```

Where your transaction manager bean definition looks something like this:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager yourTxManager() {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the answer in this post I think it is exactly what you are looking for, multiple transaction managers using a qualifier to tell @Transactional which transaction manager to use.

[Spring - Is it possible to use multiple transaction managers in the same application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423125/spring-is-it-possible-to-use-multiple-transaction-managers-in-the-same-applica)